# How can I get the current distance from earth inside the Map?

Tags: flutter, here-api

I would like to maintain the current zoom level when a location change is triggered.
Currently, I display the location as follows:

```
    _mapController.camera
      .lookAtPointWithDistance(coordinates, distanceInMetersFromPosition);
```

The problem is that the user can zoom in or out and then move and as soon as the position changes, the piece of code is triggered again. So my question is:

Is there a callback for changing the `distanceInMetersFromPosition` or can I somehow get the current `distanceInMetersFromPosition` or zoom? I didn't find any documentation about this so far.

I’m using the "HERE SDK for Flutter (explore Edition) - Version 4.3.2.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `camera` contains information about the current state. You can call the following:

`double distanceInMetersFromPosition =
 _mapController.camera.state.distanceToTargetInMeters;`

Alternatively, you can use `lookAtPoint(coordinates)` when you just want to update the location without changing the zoom. If you are interested in callbacks, you can attach an observer to the camera with `addObserver(MapCameraObserver observer)`. This will notify you whenever the user has zoomed or panned the map.